# angularjs ui router parent state change

Tags: angular-ui-router

I have a state tree like this

- state-A

  - state-A.A1
  - state-A.A2
- state-B

  - state-B.B1
  - state-B.B2

Now I have a ui-sref link in state-A.A2 which loads state-B.B2. While this works correctly the UI elements from state-A.A2 stays on the screen for a few seconds and then it is removed causing the screen to flicker.

Any hint that can address the problem is much appreciated

Comment: Do both B.B2 and A.A2 stay on the screen at the same time?  If so, I have a thought...  does this problem go away if you disable ngAnimate?

Comment: No A.A2 goes away, in fact all of A goes away and state B, child state B.B2  has to load. and that what is happening too. The problem is the elements for A.A2 is there on the screen momentarily and then it goes away.

Comment: there's nothing that would inherently cause that.  The two things that I can think of which might cause A.A2 view to hang out longer than expected are 1) animation code and 2) resolves.  That said, can you show more code, preferably in a plunk?  There's not enough information to answer this question.